# Checking type with String and NSString in Swift

Tags: string, swift, nsstring, typechecking

In Swift docs, it says

> Use the type check operator (is) to check whether an instance is of a certain subclass type. The type check operator returns true if the instance is of that subclass type and false if it is not.

Below code:

```
// Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Foundation

var aString = ""
var bString = aString
aString == bString
//true
//aString === bString
//error: type 'String' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'
var aObject:AnyObject = aString as AnyObject
var bObject:AnyObject = bString as AnyObject
aObject === bObject
//false
//aString is NSString
//error: 'NSString' is not a subtype of 'String'

var aNSString = NSString()
var bNSString = aNSString
aNSString == bNSString
//true
aNSString === bNSString
//true
//aNSString is NSString
//always true
//aNSString is String
//always true
```

A NSString instance is considered as String type. However, String type is a value type, NSString type is a reference type. Also, String type does not conform to AnyObject, and NSString is.

So why a NSString instance is considered as String type in type checking?

Comment: I'd assume it has something to do with the special relationship they have between NSString and String when working in Swift.  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html

Comment: It's the bridging policy that Apple uses to ensure you can use String, Double ( all new enums in Swift) as keys in a property list.

Comment: I know it uses bridge. However, I don't know what the bridge definition is. Is this a good bridge practice or not. For me, maybe this is not a good bridge between pure value and reference value. It just mixed the boundary.